# node.js select query results to send as telegram bot answer

Tags: mysql, node.js, select, telegram-bot

Need a little help to understand MySQL query result.
There is table `authors` with columns `AuthorID`, `FirstName`, ..., `SearchName`.
I'd like to select from it and send values of `SearchName` as an answer of bot

This way:

```
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
const q = ctx.message.text //here I recieve a message to bot as a string to use in select
const sql = "SELECT SearchName FROM authors WHERE LastName LIKE '%"+ q +"%'";
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {

    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
    ctx.reply(results);
    console.log(q);
});
})
```

So it results this way in console:

```
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА ЮЛИЯ ИГОРЕВНА' },
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА ЕЛЕНА ВЛАДИМИРОВНА' },
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА ИРИНА ВЛАДИМИРОВНА' },
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА В К' },
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА ВЛАДИНАТА' },
  TextRow { SearchName: 'ПЕТРОВА ИРИНА' },
```

and sure same data, but unrowed view in bot answer:

```
 [{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА ЮЛИЯ ИГОРЕВНА"},{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА ЕЛЕНА ВЛАДИМИРОВНА"},{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА ИРИНА ВЛАДИМИРОВНА"},{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА В К"},{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА ВЛАДИНАТА"},{"SearchName":"ПЕТРОВА ИРИНА"},
```

So, I ask for help how to get values only and further I'd like to manage it as separated replies from bot to user. i.e. user sending string and getting as many replies as many rows query returns.

Answer (score 0):

All that's left to do now is just to loop through the results inside db query callback, craft and send the bot messages there.
Here is an example,

```
bot.on('text', (ctx) => {
    const q = ctx.message.text //here I recieve a message to bot as a string to use in select
    const sql = "SELECT SearchName FROM authors WHERE LastName LIKE '%"+ q +"%'";

    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(results);

        for (const result of results) { // each row
            ctx.reply(result.SearchName); // send the SearchName field from the object
        }
    });
})
```